# Routes Based On User Roles

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular8

My app has three user types based on roles. I would like to use same url for all this users, allowing sharing of address. So using /ticker for user role client and /admin/ticker for user role admin is not a option.

However each combination of user role and model has a specific component. So I would like to bind the route /ticker to ClientTickerComponent if the user is a client and AdminTickerComponet is the user is an admin and SomethingTickerComponent if the client is a something.

The only solution I could figure out is use a TickerComponent in route and leave that to create the specific [Rule]TickerComponent based on the auth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add routes dynamically to router

In your app.component import Router

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
```

in constructor

```
private router: Router
```

in ngOnInit for each route to add

```
let route = {};
if (role === 'Client') {
    route = {
        path: 'ticker',
        component: ClientTickerComponent
    };
}
if (role === 'Admin') {
    route = {
        path: 'ticker',
        component: AdminTickerComponent
    };
}

this.router.config.unshift(route);
```

Regards